# Why is my Mac emoji on-screen keyboard appearing scrolled to the middle of the emoji list?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, emoji

When I open the Mac emoji keyboard via ctrl+cmd+space, it usually opens scrolled to a particular place in the middle of the emoji list, rather than the top.  This is annoying!

This has been happening since I can remember, at least a couple years of Mac versions.  Currently I'm on 10.14.6.  Any ideas what the issue is?

Here's the location it always opens to.  It doesn't matter what emoji I was using previously - it opens scrolled to this exact position regardless.
[image: Emoji keyboard scrolled]

Comment: It remembers position on 10.14.5. You can try: enter the full mode, select the  "smiley and people" and then try this mini version.

Comment: @anki It doesn't appear in my case to have anything to do with remembering position - it always scrolls to that exact point when this happens, and I'm not using any of those emojis or scrolling to this position manually.

Comment: Try going to the top and clicking this button on the right to go to the full mode https://i.stack.imgur.com/m10RZ.png and select the correct panel you want to see and the switch back to the compact mode.